# Angular 5 chain service observables then return observable to component

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

I have two rest calls I need to make.  Rest call 2 depends on rest call 1. And I want to store each result in the service before proceeding. Then I want to return an observable to the component that calls rest call 1 so the component can subscribe in case of issues.

code from service:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<AuthAccess> {
// rest call 1
return this.getAuthClient()
  .flatMap(res => {
    this.client = res.body;
    // rest call 2
    return this.authenticate(username, password)
      .flatMap(access => {
        this.userAccess = access.body;
        return Observable.of(this.userAccess);
      });
  });
```

}

I can get this to chain correctly, but the component that is calling this and subscribing to the call will show an undefined response.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I cannot find responses on this exact use case.

Answer (score 5):

[Live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nygmn7?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts). 
Use a `map` operator (and the lettable operatos sintax), instead of chain a new `flatMap`.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
      // rest call 1
      return this.getAuthClient()
          .pipe(flatMap(res => {
              this.client = res.body;
              // rest call 2
              return this.authenticate(username, password)
                  .pipe(map(access => {
                      this.userAccess = access.body;
                      return this.userAccess;
                  }));
          }));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works great.  I was able to get it to work also by changing the return type in my authenticate function from Observable<HttpResponse<AuthAccess>> to just Observable<AuthAccess> which didn't seem like a good solution so I really appreciate the help.  I have upvoted but it doesn't show cause i'm not cool enough yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: If it works I am happy. Consider to get used with lettable operators (pipeable), you can take a glance here, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md.