# Create a chain of observables and return an observable after all of them finished

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a service in angular 6 with a method "saveEntity" that saves an entity performing multiple requests. I need to do the following:
the method call an url --> once obtained the response i need to call another url --> once obtained this second response too, i need to return the final data to the Component.

So in my component i will have

```
service.saveEntity(entity).subscribe();
```

Into the service, what i need to do?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? That would help in finding a solution and understanding exactly what you mean.

Comment: use 'rxjs/operator' switchMap

Comment: I found this solution too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659837/angular-5-chain-service-observables-then-return-observable-to-component

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MultiSaveService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    saveMultipleInParallel(): Observable<[string, number]> {
        return forkJoin([
            this.http.post<string>('my-url', {
                stringData: 'stringData'
            }),
            this.http.post<number>('my-url', {
                numberData: 1
            })
        ])
    }

    saveMultipleOneByOne(): Observable<[string, number]> {
        return this.http.post<string>('url', {stringData: 'stringData'}).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.http.post<number>('url', {numberData: 5}))
        )
    }
}
```

Your subscribe should look like

```
this.multiSaveService.saveMultipleInParallel()
  .subscribe(([firstCallResult, secondCallResult]) => {
    console.log(firstCallResult);
    console.log(secondCallResult);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

**service.ts**

```js
firstOperation() {
  return http.get('url1')
}

secondOperation() {
  return http.get('url2')
}
```

The second service is triggered after the first service: once can use `mergeMap` or `concatMap`

```js
bothOperations1() {
  service.firstOperation().pipe(
    mergeMap(data1 => {
     // do something with data1
     return service.secondOperation()
    })
  )
}
```

But if both service are to call in parallel, `forkJoin` can be used

```js
bothOperations2() {

  return forkjoin([service.firstOperation(), service.secondOperation()])
}
```

**component.ts**

```
saveEntity1() {
  service.BothOperation1().subscribe(data => {
     // do whatever is needed with the data2
  })
}

saveEntity2() {
  service.bothOperation2().subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
     // do whatever is needed with data1 and data2
  })
}
```